# Angular 10: how to create dynamic Component / html?

Tags: html, angular, dynamic, components

2 questions:

1. `<div>{{ someData }}</div>` - how to make `{{ someData }}` to be converted to html?
2. `<div>{{ MyComponentClass }}</div>` - how to make it to create an instance of the component MyComponentClass and put it inside the div?

For question 1 I guess I need a way to get access to the DOM element and then to inject it myself.
For question 2 I have no clue but it'll be so useful.

Answer (score 1):

1. Question:

You can bind a string/html variable to the [innerHTML] attribute binding.

```
<div [innerHTML]="theHtmlString"></div>
```

If the html doesnt work you need to inject the DomSanitizer to tell angular that the html is safe.

```
 constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer) {
    this.htmlString = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(style);
  }
```

2. Question:

You can create components dynamically by using a @ViewChild and get the ViewContainerRef from your div and use the componentFactoryResolver:

Template:

```
<div #yourdiv></div>
```

Component:

```
@ViewChild("yourdiv" , {read: ViewContainerRef}) private vcr: ViewContainerRef;
   
constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {

    let resolver = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(DynamicComponent);
    let componentFactory =  this.vcr.createComponent(resolver);
  
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. 1 is easy to understand. 2 I don't really understand what's going on there. All I want to do is to simulate what you can do easily in React: to put children inside a custom component: <component><child></child></component>. If it's so complicated then I'll use the ugly way of put all the options inside a component + parameter to select the right option. Limited, but this is Angular.

Comment: You want to create a component dynamically by clicking a button or you just want to add a component the "normal" way? You can always use the component tag in the template to create a new instance of the component like: <child-component></child-component>. Sorry if i did not understand you correctly and angular might be hard at first but once you in it i don't know what i could not do.

Comment: I know that inside my component's template I can do:

<other-component></other-component>

It's working fine, but I want to do:

<other-component>some code here</other-component>

so I'll be able to create HOC like in React. The problem is that in Angular I can't pass children to the children.

Comment: Oh now i get you. Angular can do this. In your parent component you need to use the  <ng-content></ng-content> Tag to tell angular where to put the html you write inside its own tag. Now you do something like this: <parent-component><child-component></child-component>// some more html</parent-component> For more info you can read this: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/

Comment: I will make an example and send it to you, 8 or 10 hours later (with node js server and angular client)